# How can I emulate Having count in EF query

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want to select all the **ItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTreeRoot** rows, which have as an IdItemRecipesComparisonResultRoot a certain id, EXCLUDING those rows when in the table exist others rows with a different IdItemRecipesComparisonResultRoot but pointing to the same **ItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTree**. In other words, I need to select those which Tree FK is unique.

[image: Model].

I am trying first to select all  with the certain id, and then substract the ones which more than one tree, but I get stuck when counting the trees. I tried something like:

```
int certainRootId = 5;

await Context.ItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTreesRoots
        .Where(treeRoot1 => treeRoot1.IdItemRecipesComparisonResultRoot == certainRootId)
        .Except(treeRoot1 => Context.ItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTreesRoots
                                    .Where(treeRoot2 =>
                                treeRoot1.IdItemRecipesComparisonResultParent == treeRoot2.IdItemRecipesComparisonResultParent &&
                                treeRoot1.IdItemRecipesComparisonResultChild == treeRoot2.IdItemRecipesComparisonResultChild)
                                .// Here i need something like HAVING Count() > 1
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I've tried reading that a couple of times and it's doing my head in around how/why these relations are needed the way they are, but I *think* what you want is to add  `&& treeroot1.IdItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTreeRoot != treeRoot2.IdItemRecipesComparisonsResultsTreeRoot)`  This would look to exclude any Roots that have duplicated combinations of items.  Not sure that's exactly what you're looking for, but consider adding an example of IDs with the desired output...

Comment: That was a solution to my problem, thank you!
Luckily I have an autoincrement Id, so your comparation works.
How could I do it without it? I mean if the 3 FK were a PK?

Comment: It would work exactly the same because within the set of records that match the first 2 IDs, the 3rd ID would still be unique. It would exclude any row that had more than one combination of the first 2.